# Image Overlay using JS styling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

Currently, I am trying to place an overlay on top of a background image.  For some reason I just can't seem to get the background color to lay on top of the image.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I am using a lot of Material UI etc, so my styling is done using JS.

```
import React from 'react'
import Background from '../images/background.jpg'

// MUI STUFF
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container'
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  background: {
    backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`,
    position: 'relative',
    objectFit: 'cover',
    width: '100%',
    height: 400,
    paddingTop: 70,
    margin: 0
  },
  card: {
    width: '100%'
  },
  overlay: {
    position: 'absolute',
    objectFit: 'cover',
    width: '100%',
    height: 400,
    margin: 0,

    backgroundColor: '#5BC2E7'
  }
}))

const Home = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <Box>
      <div className={classes.overlay}>
        <Box className={classes.background}>
          <Container>
            Wyncode is so great and stuff. Track your jobs and stuff here.
          </Container>
        </Box>
      </div>
      <Box>
        <Container>More stuff will go here</Container>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this css:

```
background: {
    backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`,
    position: 'relative',
    objectFit: 'cover',
    width: '100%',
    height: 400,
    paddingTop: 70,
    margin: 0
},
overlay: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    margin: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#5BC2E7'
  }
```

With this html:

```
<Box>
  <Box className={classes.background}>
    <div className={classes.overlay}>
      <Container>
        Wyncode is so great and stuff. Track your jobs and stuff here.
      </Container>
    </div>
  </Box>
  <Box>
    <Container>More stuff will go here</Container>
  </Box>
</Box>
```